# jquery hide/show form elements, preventing slip of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I use the following code to show some forms, when a certain element is selected from the select input.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#callback_url" ).hide();
$("#test-url").on("change keyup paste", function(){
    //console.log($("#test-url").val());

    //generate address
    if ($("#test-url").val() == 0) {
        console.log("true");

        $( "#callback_url" ).hide();
        $( "#api_key" ).show();
    }

    //payload
    else{
        console.log("else");

        $( "#api_key" ).hide();
        $( "#callback_url" ).show();

    }

})

});
```

My HTML code looks like this (using bootstrap):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="test-url" size="5">
        <option selected value="0">Generate new address</option>
        <option value="1">Receive callback</option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <form id="test-form">
      <div class="form-group" data-url="/api/receive?method=create">
        <input type="text" id="api_key" class="form-control" name="api_key" placeholder="API-Key">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group test-specific-inputs" data-url="/api/receive?method=check_logs">
        <input type="text" id="callback_url" class="form-control" name="callback_url" placeholder="Callback URL">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-info btn-lg">Send Request</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

All in all I've got two questions:

> 1.) Is it good style to use javascript at the top of document ready to hide the element, when page is loaded? If not, what to use instead of?
>
> 2.) When I load the page the first time it looks like [image: this]
>
> Now when clicking "Receive callback" it looks like:
>   [image: this]
>
> How is this caused, and how can I prevent the input form to "slip" down like it does, when changing the selected element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Using `$(document).ready` waits for the page to load and this means that the javascript code inside that function will run once the HTML has finished loading and rendering. This is useful when you are working with HTML elements from your JS code. I would suggest using `$(document).ready` to make sure you can place all you script libraries in the `<head>` and know that there won't be a chance of an undefined element that was yet to be rendered.

2) I used your exact code with bootstrap 3.3.7 and it seems to work fine, so I think there is a problem with your parts of your HTML or CSS that you didn't include here. See for yourself:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#callback_url" ).hide();
$("#test-url").on("change keyup paste", function(){
    //console.log($("#test-url").val());

    //generate address
    if ($("#test-url").val() == 0) {
        console.log("true");

        $( "#callback_url" ).hide();
        $( "#api_key" ).show();
    }

    //payload
    else{
        console.log("else");

        $( "#api_key" ).hide();
        $( "#callback_url" ).show();

    }

})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="test-url" size="5">
        <option selected value="0">Generate new address</option>
        <option value="1">Receive callback</option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <form id="test-form">
      <div class="form-group" data-url="/api/receive?method=create">
        <input type="text" id="api_key" class="form-control" name="api_key" placeholder="API-Key">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group test-specific-inputs" data-url="/api/receive?method=check_logs">
        <input type="text" id="callback_url" class="form-control" name="callback_url" placeholder="Callback URL">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-info btn-lg">Send Request</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers